# How to get this "Resident Evil" photo effect

Tags: hdr, reverse-engineering, indoor

Surfing on the Internet I found [this](https://plus.google.com/photos/110146939041400933746/albums/5872697823715462577?banner=pwa) amazing album by Jeff Lazell.

I'm wondering how he got those tones and textures. I really like them.

Any ideas of the techniques to produce those effects?

**Edited:** [This](https://plus.google.com/photos/110146939041400933746/albums/5785537476102332657) Lazell's album is also a good one.

Comment: I suspect liberal use of the clarity slider in Lightroom, careful application of HDR to really bring the details out and possibly a colour filter in front of the lens.

Comment: I’m closing this question because the linked photos being asked about are no longer available.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the basic things I can see is that everything uses a red shifted color balance.  It gives more of a rust look.  Also shifting the gamma down to make things dark but high contrast (brights are still bright, but a larger portion of the image is in the darker range).  There may also be some desaturation to make colors look more faded and aged.

It also appears to be a wide angle lens using the natural vignette of the lens to give it a rustic kind of feel.  They have a very similar feel to what I get out of my Canon 17-40 F/4L, though it appears he shoots Nikon from the gold ring on his lens in his profile picture.

The fact he's actually shooting old and warn down subject matter doesn't hurt any either.

Comment: I suppose he is also altering selectively the colors of the objects with an edition software. It is more notorious in the "Ask the Dust" album. It seems a very detailed work.

Comment: @Memochipan - I'm not sure that it is selective color so much as saturation adjustments either to less or more saturation.  Most of Ask The Dust seems to have pretty broad saturation boosting in addition to a lot of use of HDR techniques.

Comment: These are almost certainly HDR shots.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect in some of his images he chased a photograph through some HDR tonemapping software (Oloneo, Photomatix) which regularly leeds to such effects.

(You can used the editing on single exposures as well - without stacked images for HDR.)

In terms of using a "regular photo editor", you add a lot of "clarity" or "sharpness" (not via RAW sharpening but the "fake" sharpening that uses a change in brightness to make it look sharper) as well as some de-saturation. Add in some extra contrast to support the effect even more.

You possibly also want some dynamic range reduction i.e. brighten up the shadows, darken down the highlights - lastly tweak saturation.

Looking at the linked images, I would say that some are multiple exposure HDRs (interior lit + outside scene in window) and the most key settings would be the sharpening. (Not the RAW sharpening but the thing that introduces halos.)